# Is there a way to pull data-range in AWS Athena when the timestamp is big int using mySQL & PrestoDB?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, amazon-athena, presto, date-arithmetic

I am trying to query from a table where I am particularly interested to pull the last 7 days from the `timestamp` column. The `timestamp` column has been stored in the table as `big int`.

I tried using this after converting the 'big int' timestamp to 'datetime' using FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp).

The query I am tried to pull the timestamp for the last 7 days (from 15th Nov) is as follows-

```
SELECT * FROM activation WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) > '+51819-11-15' LIMIT 10;
```

Basically after converting 'big int'to 'datetime' I looked at the timestamp column, pulled a date which in the above example shows that the data that I took was Nov 15th, 2019 (not at all the most efficient way to run this query)

When I run my query in Athena I get the following error-

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:57: '>' cannot be applied to timestamp, varchar(12)
```

Can someone help me with a more better/efficient way to achieve this in Athena.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reversing the logic and compare the stored unix timestamp to a value that represents the timestamp 7 days back. The advantage of this approach is that the query will happily use an existing index on the `timestamp` column.

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM activation WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 LIMIT 10;
```

`7 * 24 * 60 * 60` represents 7 days as seconds.

This can also be expressed like:

```
SELECT * FROM activation WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 10;
```

In PrestoDB:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activation 
WHERE timestamp > TO_UNIXTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7' DAY) LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I tried the first query and get an error back as: Function unix_timestamp not registered. Not sure if there is a separate function i need to use in Athena to make this work. Looked at the PrestoDB documentation as well- [https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html]

Comment: @Raj: it was unclear to me whether you were using MySQL or PrestoDB. The answer was for MySQL, I just added a query for Presto.

Comment: My apologies @GMB but this query works for me! What does CURRENT_TIMESTAMP do? does it take the 'current' value for the column 'timestamp'

Comment: @Raj: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current timestamp (as of now). `- INTERVAL '7' DAY` substract 7 days to that, meaning basically : 7 days ago. You basically want to select all the timestamps that are more recent than that.

Comment: thank you @GMB for explaining it in simple terms. now i understand!